# Force, strict dependencies and constraints doesn't work in build.gradle for slf4j-api

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to upgrade transitive dependency version of `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` to 2.0.12, but nothing except excluding transitive dependency works. 
I have tried next things in my build.gradle to achieve this:

- configured forced dependency, according to this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#forced_dependencies_vs_strict_dependencies)
- configured strict dependency, according to this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version)
- added constraint following this [link](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps)

But nothing from above worked, except excluding `org.slf4j:slf4j-api` dependency from `org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core`

Here is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

ext {
    javaMainClass = 'org.example.Main'
}

application {
    mainClassName = javaMainClass
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

// configuring forced dependency according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#forced_dependencies_vs_strict_dependencies
configurations {
    compileClasspath {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation platform('org.junit:junit-bom:5.9.1')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    implementation(platform("org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-google-cloud-platform-bom:2.53.0"))
    implementation("org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core")
    implementation("org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java")
    
    implementation ("org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core")
    // to make slf4j-api version 2.0.12 be used by gradle, uncomment below org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core implementation with exclude and comment upper one without exclusion
//    implementation ("org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core") {
//        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-api'
//    }

    // adding constraint according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_constraints.html#sec:adding-constraints-transitive-deps
    constraints {
        implementation ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12") {
            "because need latest version"
        }
    }
    // configuring strict dependency according to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html#sec:enforcing_dependency_version
    implementation ("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12") {
        version {
            strictly '2.0.12'
        }
    }
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.12'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Only excluding transitive dependency makes `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12` to be used in application.

Here is the output of `gradle -q dependencyInsight --dependency 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api'`:

```
org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12
  Variant compile:
    | Attribute Name                 | Provided | Requested    |
    |--------------------------------|----------|--------------|
    | org.gradle.status              | release  |              |
    | org.gradle.category            | library  | library      |
    | org.gradle.libraryelements     | jar      | classes      |
    | org.gradle.usage               | java-api | java-api     |
    | org.gradle.dependency.bundling |          | external     |
    | org.gradle.jvm.environment     |          | standard-jvm |
    | org.gradle.jvm.version         |          | 17           |
   Selection reasons:
      - Forced
      - By constraint

org.slf4j:slf4j-api:{strictly 2.0.12} -> 2.0.12
\--- compileClasspath

org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12
+--- compileClasspath
\--- org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.12
     \--- compileClasspath

org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7 -> 2.0.12
\--- org.apache.avro:avro:1.8.2
     +--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0
     |    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0
     |    |    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-google-cloud-platform-bom:2.53.0
     |    |         \--- compileClasspath
     |    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-java:2.53.0
     |         +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
     |         \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:2.53.0
     |              +--- compileClasspath (requested org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core)
     |              \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
     \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-avro:2.53.0
          +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
          \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0 (*)

org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 2.0.12
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0
|    |    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-google-cloud-platform-bom:2.53.0
|    |         \--- compileClasspath
|    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-java:2.53.0
|         +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
|         \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:2.53.0
|              +--- compileClasspath (requested org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core)
|              \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-java:2.53.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.53.0
|    +--- compileClasspath (requested org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java)
|    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core:2.53.0
|    +--- compileClasspath (requested org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-core)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-direct-java:2.53.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:2.53.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-java:2.53.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-fn-execution:2.53.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
|    |    +--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-java:2.53.0 (*)
|    |    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0 (*)
|    \--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-avro:2.53.0
|         +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
|         \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core:2.53.0 (*)
+--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-fn-execution:2.53.0 (*)
\--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-transform-service-launcher:2.53.0
     +--- org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-bom:2.53.0 (*)
     \--- org.apache.beam:beam-runners-core-construction-java:2.53.0 (*)

(*) - Indicates repeated occurrences of a transitive dependency subtree. Gradle expands transitive dependency subtrees only once per project; repeat occurrences only display the root of the subtree, followed by this annotation.

A web-based, searchable dependency report is available by adding the --scan option.
8:16:22 PM: Execution finished 'dependencyInsight --dependency 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api' -q'.
```

I expected to see conflict of versions and `slf4j-api` of version 1.7.30 to be chosen, due to some reasons (which I don't understand for now).
But instead I see `slf4j-api` of version '2.0.12' in output.

I am sure that version `slf4j-api:1.7.30` is used, because I imported `slf4j-simple:2.0.12`, which is not compatible with `slf4j-api:1.7.30`, so NOP implementation is chosen and you will see that in logs output, when you run `gradle run`.

JDK version: Amazon Coretto version 17 
Gradle version: 8.6